# Setting Network via powershell not working as expected

Tags: powershell, powercli

CSV

[image: CSV]

I am trying to pull info from a CSV and use invoke-vmscript to change ip addresses on a specific network adapter (filtered by interface index).

But am receiving the following error

New-NetIPAddress : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'IPAddress'
because it is an empty string.

Set-DnsClientServerAddress : Cannot validate argument on parameter
'InterfaceIndex'. The argument is null. Provide a
|  valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.

[image]

I have a csv file headered as above

```
`$vms = Import-CSV "C:\\Scripts\\servers.csv"
$GC = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Please enter credentials", "Enter       Guest credentials for VM",   "xxxx", "")

foreach ($vm in $vms){
$VMName = $vm.Name
 $IP = $vm.IP
$SNM = $vm.SubnetMask
$GW = $vm.Gateway
 $DNS1 = $vm.DNS1
$DNS2 = $vm.DNS2
$adapter = Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMname -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText '(Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription Vm\*).ifindex' -GuestUser xxx -GuestPassword xxx
Write-Host "Setting IP address for $VMname..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
Sleep -Seconds 60
$ip1 = Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMname -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText '(New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex         $adapter -IPAddress $IP -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $GW)'
$ip2 = Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMname -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText '(Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $adapter -ServerAddresses ("$DNS1","$DNS2"))'
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $adapter -ServerAddresses ("$DNS1","$DNS2")
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMname -GuestCredential $GC -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText $ip1
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMname -GuestCredential $GC -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText $ip2
Write-Host "Setting IP address completed." -ForegroundColor Green
Sleep -Seconds 20
(\[WMIClass\]"\\$vmname\\ROOT\\CImv2:Win32_Process").Create("cmd.exe /c ipconfig /registerdns")
}`
```

thing is if i run the variable $ip i get the ip provided back to me

also if i run these commands directly on a host it works ok

```
connect-viserver xxx
$vms = Import-CSV "\\in1grascm001\Source_Files\New-Nicservers.csv"
$adapter = (get-netadapter -InterfaceDescription Vm*).IfIndex
foreach ($vm in $vms){
$IP = $vm.ip
$GW = $vm.Gateway
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $adapter -IPAddress $ip -PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway $vm.Gateway
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $adapter -ServerAddresses ("x.x.x.x","x.x.x.x")
Sleep -Seconds 20
([WMIClass]"\\$vmname\ROOT\CImv2:Win32_Process").Create("cmd.exe /c ipconfig /registerdns")
}
```

Comment: Use double-quotes (`"..."`) instead of single-quotes (`'...'`) if you want PowerShell to expand `$adapter`

Comment: Hi Mathias, At which part, when i am filling the $adapter variable or when i am using it as a variable?

Thank you

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
Thanks, so i put double quotes around each of the lines where adapter is called and i get this error,

https://ibb.co/gVKcWxY

I checked and each of the variables Vmname, adapter, IP nd GW are filled with correct info

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the output from `Invoke-VMScript` has trailing whitespace? `$adapter = $adapter.Trim()`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen

That seemsed to do the trick, without it this was the variable in $adapter

https://ibb.co/vV96TGN

Then when i added $adapter = $adapter.Trim() this was the variable

https://ibb.co/9yJv3TP

So when i ran it i got this wall of text

https://ibb.co/7JPxPyx

However it DID still go ahead and set the ip address on the remote computer

How Odd

Thank you for your knowledge